# How to Encode All Columns of type Categorica in a Pandas Dataframe as Dummy Variables

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a Pandas dataframe with a large number of categorical columns which I wish to pass to scikit-learn.  Since scikit-learn only accepts arrays as arguments, I need to convert all of the categorical columns to dummy variables.  For example, I have a religion column with categories "Christian", "Muslim", and "Hindu" which should be converted to three dummy variables which are set to 0 or 1 based on these values.

The best solution I've found is to split up the dataframe into the categorical variables and the non-categorical variables, then use pandas.get_dummies on all the categorical variables, and then recombine.

Is there a faster way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take your dataframe (df) and pass it in to the get_dummies() call along with the list of columns that you'd like to convert.

Lets say you have a df with a bunch of columns and you'd like to create dummy variables just from the "Religion" column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Adam', 'Brad', 'Charlie', 'David','Eric'],
                   'Religion': ['Christian', 'Hindu', 'Muslim','Hindu','Christian'],
                   'Age': [28, 25, 35, 24, 39,],
                   'State':['CA','CA','AZ','NV','OR']})
```

Here's what the df looks like:

```
   Age     Name   Religion State
0   28     Adam  Christian    CA
1   25     Brad      Hindu    CA
2   35  Charlie     Muslim    AZ
3   24    David      Hindu    NV
4   39     Eric  Christian    OR
```

To create dummy variables of the "Religion" column:

```
df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Religion'])
```

Output:

```
   Age     Name State  Religion_Christian  Religion_Hindu  Religion_Muslim
0   28     Adam    CA                   1               0                0
1   25     Brad    CA                   0               1                0
2   35  Charlie    AZ                   0               0                1
3   24    David    NV                   0               1                0
4   39     Eric    OR                   1               0                0
```